# Android List row tablelayout issue

Tags: android, padding, tablelayout

I've been fiddling about for nearly an hour and not figured this out so looking for some help.

As you can see in my image here the second row doesn't show the checkbox. It's been pushed off screen to the right due to the long text.

[image: rows]

What I would like is for the image on the Left to always be in that place, and the checkbox on the right to always be in that place. The title text in the middle should fit between those two things wrapping to as many lines as it needs.

I did make it work by setting the 'Ems' property but I don't think that was the right way to solve this.

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/bg_ffa_1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_row_title_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:textColor="#3A3C3B"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:text="Article 1" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
                <CheckBox 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I've sussed it. No sooner than positing the question do I figure it out.

The key was to add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to the linear layout that is wrapping the textview, simple when you know!

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Comment: Hm, I would need to guess the textview width though right? How would that work across different screen sizes?

Comment: No. The point of RelativeLayout is that you can position elements relative to each other.

Comment: Right but if I have something like, checkbox is left of textview, how do I ensure the checkbox stays visible on screen when the textview has a long string?

Comment: Use `layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the checkbox, so that it aligns to the right side of parent container.

Answer (score 0):

This layout for your listview item should get you the desired result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView    android:id="@+id/myImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
  <TextView     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/myImage"/>
  <CheckBox     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```